# Python - Calculating Time Difference from Text File

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am very new to Python and i'm having some problems. I have a text file containing the following information:

```
[Name, Start Time, Finish Time]

Xantippe 09:00 11:00
Erica 10:00 12:06
Marcia 09:30 11:45
Elizabeth 10:15 12:10
Angela 11:30 13:45
Freda 12:00 14:20
Maria 12:30 14:10
```

I need to be able to read the text file, take the start and finish time for each person, calculate the time difference and write the information to a file listing the times in ascending order. I have standard methods to calculate the time difference between two times, and to sort through information as below, however I am unable to identify the times from the text file and carry out the task. Could anybody please help?

---

```
import datetime as dt


class TimeCalc:
    start = "09:35:23"
    end = "10:23:00"
    start_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M:%S')
    end_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(end, '%H:%M:%S')
    diff = (end_dt - start_dt)
    diff.seconds / 60

    print(diff)
```

---

```
with open('Lad.txt') as fin:
    lines = [line.split() for line in fin]

    from operator import itemgetter
lines.sort(key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True)

with open('sortdesc.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for el in lines:
        fout.write('{0}\n'.format(' '.join(el)))
```

Comment: It looks like you wanted to put each name on a new line. You can do this by putting two space characters at the end of each line.

Comment: Does your input also contain brackets at each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not totally clear on your formatting.  for comma delimited and time like `12:00:00`, this should work:

```
from datetime import datetime

def time_diff(start, end):
    start_dt = datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M:%S')
    end_dt = datetime.strptime(end, '%H:%M:%S')
    diff = (end_dt - start_dt)
    return diff.seconds

scores = {}
with open('input.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin.readlines():
        values = line.split(',')
        scores[values[0]] = time_diff(values[1],values[2])

with open('sorted.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for key, value in sorted(scores.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (v,k)):
        fout.write('%s,%s\n' % (key, value))
```

Comment: It is probably worth saying that if his input also contains brackets (not clear from his question in my opinion) then this can easily be removed by using strip("[", "]") on values[0] and values[2] in your code.

Comment: @jpwagner apologies, I copied and pasted the wrong error message, it meant to say   line 17, in <module>
    scores[values[0]] = time_diff(values[1], values[2])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: `values` for that line does not have 3 values when splitting by comma.  This is because of your file format...check if it's commas or spaces or tabs etc.  add error handling if sometimes a line has another format...this is where it's harder to help since it's *your* project

Comment: @jpwagnerThis is exactly how it is written in the .txt file. The values are only separated by spaces. Is this what you mean?                                                    Xantippe 09:00 11:00
Erica 10:00 12:06
Marcia 09:30 11:45
Elizabeth 10:15 12:10
Angela 11:30 13:45
Freda 12:00 14:20
Maria 12:30 14:10

Comment: then the time format should be `%H:%M` and the delimiter should be `line.split(' ')`

Comment: is each entry on a different line or is the whole thing one line?

Comment: @jpwagner No it's not all on one line, its just the way it appears on here when I posed the comment. sorry about that. on each line there is the Name Start Time Finish Time. The Times are in Hours and Minutes.

Comment: ok, then change it like i said in my last comment and it should work.

Comment: @jpwagner So just change it to hours and minutes, i'm not sure that you meant by the line split though. This is really new to me. Sorry to be hard work.

Comment: Before-->After: `(',')`-->`(' ')` and `'%H:%M:%S'`-->`'%H:%M'`

Comment: @jpwagner I'm not getting more error messages: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pdhalliwelluk/PycharmProjects/Web_Based_Programming/sort_desc.py", line 16, in <module>
    scores[values[0]] = time_diff(values[1], values[2])
  File "/Users/pdhalliwelluk/PycharmProjects/Web_Based_Programming/sort_desc.py", line 8, in time_diff
    end_dt = datetime.strptime(end, '%H:%M')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:

Comment: That is basically telling you that the string format does not match `%H:%M`

Comment: @jpwagner Ah okay, why would that be?

Comment: first make a test file "Joe 12:00 13:00\nLucy 2:00 4:00\n" and make sure it works, then look more closely at your real file.  i'm positive you can figure it out now that you've come this far.  good luck!