# Error when finding difference in times

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7, pycharm

I have the following information stored in a text file called Lad.txt This is the name, start time and finish time, not separated by commas, with each entry on a new line:

```
Xantippe 09:00 11:00  
Erica 10:00 12:06  
Marcia 09:30 11:45  
Elizabeth 10:15 12:10  
Angela 11:30 13:45  
Freda 12:00 14:20  
Maria 12:30 14:10
```

I am using the following code to try and calculate the difference between the start and finish time for each entrant, and print the results to a file in ascending order. However, I am getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pdhalliwelluk/PycharmProjects/Web_Based_Programming/sort_desc.py", line 16, in <module>  
    scores[values[0]] = time_diff(values[1], values[2])
  File "/Users/pdhalliwelluk/PycharmProjects/Web_Based_Programming/sort_desc.py", line 8, in time_diff
    end_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, '%H:%M')  
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:
```

The code is as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime


def time_diff(start, end):  
    start_dt = datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M')  
    end_dt = datetime.strptime(end, '%H:%M')  
    diff = (end_dt - start_dt)  
    return diff.seconds / 60  

scores = {}
with open('Lad.txt') as fin:  
    for line in fin.readlines():  
        values = line.split(' ')  
        scores[values[0]] = time_diff(values[1], values[2])  

with open('sorted.txt', 'w') as fout:  
    for key, value in sorted(scores.iteritems(), key=lambda (k, v): (v, k)):  
        fout.write('%s,%s\n' % (key, value))
```

Comment: `readlines()` does not strip newlines for you.

Comment: @user2357112 Is this what is causing me the problems? How do I rectify this? Thanks.

Comment: `strip` the newlines. (Also, don't use `readlines`. If you just need to iterate over the lines, `for line in fin` works without reading the whole file into memory at once if it's a big file.)

Comment: @user2357112 Ah right. Thanks. I understand what you mean about reading the whole file. I'm quite new to this though, and not too sure how exactly to strip the new lines.

Comment: this is a continuation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359461/python-calculating-time-difference-from-text-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing line 13 to:

```
values = line.strip().split(' ')
```